How to download Up to 1 Year of Event Log Files
I am trying to download the event log files with up to 1 year of data but its showing data for only 1 month.
I have enabled Retain event log files in Event Monitoring Settings and updated the eventLogRetentionDuration field in EventSettings xml
This feature is released in summer 24
Link: Download Up to 1 year of Event Log Files

When did you have event monitoring enabled in your org, also can you see logs using https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/ ?

Hi @Vinay, The issue is resolved it giving me the data from the date I enabled Retain event log files

Good to know, however you can try using 

32
.  'eventLogRetentionDuration' Specifies the number of days (between 30 and 365) (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_eventsettings.htm)
